# Mapping issue due to case sensitive logic

Tags: vba, powerbi, powerquery

I am working on power Query project project where there are multiple mapping are done based on one or two tables, but challenge that I see is case sensitive logic.

Like master table has values Prakash, prakash and mapping table has Prakash, so power query works on cell that is matches i.e. Prakash. This is one case but there are lot as I connected pq with database.

Please suggest on this. My entire project is on hold due to this issue

Answer (score 1):

You have three options.

In Power Query you can use [Text.proper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-proper)

This will capitalise the first letter of each word, so for example you would have

```
New Column = Text.proper("prakash")
```

Would return "Prakash".

The other two options would be to Text.upper which would return "prakash" as "PRAKASH" or Text.lower which would return "Prakash" as "prakash". You then map on these new converted columns.